# Combining 2 separate sql queries with separate select statement

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql and vb so I'm wondering if anybody can help me out this is the table that I have now

```
id total_leadsource total_opportunity
2   1                 3
2   8                 16
```

and i want to combine the total_leadsource and total_opportunity of the same id

```
SELECT distinct id,LeadSource,SUM (WeightedAmount) as Weighted_Amount,
       COUNT(distinct oppLeadSourceID) + COUNT (distinct case when oppLeadSourceID is null then 0 end) as Total_LeadSource,
       count(OppLeadSourceID) as Total_Opportunity
FROM leadS A
LEFT JOIN opportunity B on B.Source = A.id
WHERE (OwnerCode =1486 
       OR AOCode =1486 
       OR PM = 1486 )
GROUP BY id,LeadSource
UNION 
SELECT distinct id,LeadSource,SUM (WeightedAmount) as Weighted_Amount,
       COUNT(distinct oppLeadSourceID) + COUNT (distinct case when oppLeadSourceID is null then 0 end) as Total_LeadSource,
       count(OppLeadSourceID) as Total_Opportunity
FROM leadS  A
LEFT JOIN opportunity B on B.Source = A.id
WHERE (OwnerCode =55856 
       OR AOCode =55856 
       OR PM = 55856 )
GROUP BY id,LeadSource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `UNION`. Just use a `WHERE` clause that matches both conditions.

```
SELECT id,LeadSource,SUM (WeightedAmount) as Weighted_Amount,
       COUNT(distinct oppLeadSourceID) + COUNT(distinct case when oppLeadSourceID is null then 0 end) as Total_LeadSource,
       COUNT(OppLeadSourceID) as Total_Opportunity
FROM leadS A
LEFT JOIN opportunity B on B.Source = A.id
WHERE (OwnerCode IN (1486, 55856)
       OR AOCode IN (1486, 55856)
       OR PM IN (1486, 55856))
GROUP BY id,LeadSource
```

Also note that you don't need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` when using `GROUP BY`, since the latter ensures that each row will be distinct.